# How do I add myself to the video group after installing AMDGPU-PRO driver?

Tags: drivers, video, amd-graphics, video-player, groups

I'm trying to install AMDGPU-PRO 16.40 but after installation I can't add myself to the video group. I've tried running `sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME` but after going into groups all I can see is `morgan adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare`. Should I just cut my losses, uninstall the driver and continue without, or is there something else stopping me from adding myself to the video group? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you restart your system?

Comment: Last time I tried this using the exact same steps and restarted I got a black screen on start-up  and had to reinstall. I'd rather not go through it again because I know it will probably not work.

Comment: Restarting is extreme - it should be sufficient to start a new login shell (e.g. `su - username`) or at the most, log out and back in from the GUI

Comment: I logged out and back in and it worked! Thank you soo much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just to sum up with some of the great information from steeldriver in the comments;

Install drivers following AMD's instructions

Copy `sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME` into a terminal

Type `groups`.

If `video` isn't listed, then log out and log back in. (Thanks again steeldriver)

Hopefully, you should be able to log in.

Go into a terminal and type `groups` again

If everything went according to plan, then `video` should be listed alongside other groups.

Comment: Logging out then back in worked for me.